# Why the the initial and final population hasn't the same order of magnitude?

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I minimize the objective function `y = abs(x-1)` in MATLAB and I observe
the computation of the output results. I define an initial population that contains a set of values. 
For example `initialPopulation = [100;70;100;200;200]`. `populationSize` is equal to `5`. 
MATLAB outputes the optimum `population`, the `score`, the value of the 
objective function - `fval` and the value of the objective function's variable - `x`.

#### main function

```
function [x,fval,exitflag,output,population,score] = opt_001()  
%% This is an auto generated MATLAB file from Optimization Tool.  
nvars = 1;  
%% Start with the default options  
a = [100;70;100;200;200];  
options = gaoptimset;  
%% Modify options setting  
options = gaoptimset(options,'Display','iter');  
options = gaoptimset(options,'Generations', 61,'StallGenLimit',60);  
options = gaoptimset(options,'InitialPopulation',a,'PopulationSize',5);  
[x,fval,exitflag,output,population,score] = ...  
ga(@opt,nvars,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options);
```

#### objective function

```
function [y] = opt(t)  
y = abs( t - 1 )
```

#### Outputs

```
x = 1.1472
fval = 0.1472
output = 
  problemtype: 'unconst…'
     rngstate: [1x1 struct]
  generations: 61
    funccount: 310
      message: 'Optimiz…'
maxconstraint: []

population =
1.1472
1.2929
1.2929
1.1472
1.2929
score =
0.1472
0.2929
0.2929
0.1472
0.2929
```

I expect the initial and final population to have the same values space.
In contrast looking the results, it seems that the best value of the 
final population converges to the variable's value `x` of the objective function. 
Respectively, score's value is the same as objective function's value `fval`

I think it is strange, and I thought 
it would be a good idea to talk about this.
Isn't weird that the the initial and final 
population hasn't the same order of magnitude?
Is there any idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What ist "order of magnitude"?

Comment: I'm sorry I was searching about the correct phrase. I mean 'rough estimate' of the value. For example the rough estimate of `population` element value I would like to be different from the rough estimate of the varible's `x` value.

Comment: But 'x' is one element of your 'population'. How can those two differ?

Comment: No it isn't. I mean, the `population` values are the elements of the vector `a` as x is the objective function's variable. In order to find the best population I must minimize my objective function. (x ~= 1, as y =~ 0)

Comment: I don't think so. `a` ist the initial population, `population` ist the final population. `score` are the values of the objective function of `population`. `x` is the result of the optimization process -> the best individual and `fval` is the value of the objective function of `x`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But it doesn't make sense that the final population `population` will be a set of values that their value's range will be the same as `x` and different from the initial population `a` range of values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113433/discussion-between-panos-deemac-and-steffen).